# Calculate Area Tangent Circumferences - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, area

I have the following function that calculates an area.

It receives three parameters, the first is an n representing the number of cases, the 2nd representing the radio of circumferences, and the 3rd is l giving me back the result.

The problem I have is that when the 1st input is greater than 1 it does not work.

This my code:

```
as(1, [X], A) :-
   A is (sqrt(3.0) * (X*X)) - (3.14 * (X*X))/2.
as(N, [H|_T], A) :-
   A is (sqrt(3.0) * (H*H)) - (3.14 * (H*H))/2,
   N1 is N-1,
   as(N1-1, T, A).
```

An example of how it should work is:

```
?- as(4, [1,1,1,1], R).
R = 0.162050807568877130000 ;
R = 0.162050807568877130000 ;
R = 0.162050807568877130000 ;
R = 0.162050807568877130000.
```

If you could help me, I would be grateful ...

Comment: A predicate should start with a **lowercase**.

Comment: You probably want your recursive call to be `as(N1, T, A)` instead of `as(N1-1, T, A)`. What is the purpose of the first argument to `as/3`? It seems like you could just process the list until it is empty. I think you could delete the whole first clause in that case, since once the list is empty it won't match anything.

Comment: Isn't the number redundant information with the length of the 2nd argument list?

Comment: By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason this version isn't sufficient to your needs?

```
as([H|_], A):- 
  A is (sqrt(3.0) * (H*H)) - (3.14 * (H*H))/2.
as([_|T], A) :- as(T, A).
```

Or maybe this?

```
area(H, Area) :- 
  Area is (sqrt(3.0) * (H*H)) - (3.14 * (H*H))/2.
as(List, Area) :- member(Ratio, List), area(Ratio, Area).
```

1. I don't understand why you need to worry about `N` at all.
2. Matching both `N` and `[X]` leads to redundancy. You shouldn't have to repeat your formula.
3. You have a lot of singleton errors: `_T` in the head, and then `T` in the body which will not work.
4. You are passing `N1-1` to the recursive call, which will not cause it to be evaluated—but you already evaluated `N-1` in the previous expression, so just pass `N1` here. Again, I don't see the point of this at all.
5. I think it's a good idea to use `succ(N1, N)` instead of adding or subtracting one, because it works in both directions (not relevant here, of course).
6. It feels a bit icky to be combining the list traversal with the calculation to me. I would in general break things down so that the calculation is separate from the data structure insofar as that can be done. This is a universal maxim of programming.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to compute the area for every measurement anyway, would it not be opportune to get a list of areas corresponding to the list of radio measurements? The structure of your predicate as/3 seems to indicate that you were thinking along those lines. And you could easily achieve that by using maplist/3:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).   % needed for maplist

% a single measurement and the corresponding area
area(X, A) :-
   A is (sqrt(3.0) * (X*X)) - (3.14 * (X*X))/2.

areas(Xs,As) :-
   maplist(area,Xs,As).          % area/2 mapped to Xs results in As
```

Querying this predicate yields the desired results but in a list:

```
?- areas([1,1,5,3],As).
As = [0.16205080756887713, 0.16205080756887713, 4.051270189221931, 1.4584572681198935].
```